# A number is defined as a 3den if it is a multiple of 3 or has the digit 3 in it. Given a number as input, determine whether it is a 3den or not

Tags: java

```
public boolean is3den(int num){
    if(num%10==0)
        return true;
    while(num>0){
        if(num%10==3)
            return true;
        else {
            num=num/10;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My code passes every true condition but didn't passes false, any suggestion?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what do you mean by passes false? Are you looking for false to be returned from this method ?

Comment: You should have `if(num%3==0) return true;` as the first test

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean is3den(int num){
    if((num%3)==0)
        return true;
    while(num>0){
        if((num%10)==3)
            return true;
        else {
            num=num/10;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```